# Punctuating a vertical list that is introduced by a question

Tags: punctuation, lists, question-mark

I have searched online but can't find anything definitive on which of the following is preferable:

> Incorrect. What could you infer from these quotes:
>
> - 'most of the dogs jump on the meat'
> - 'Old Talon stares at his meat'

vs.

> Incorrect. What could you infer from these quotes?
>
> - 'most of the dogs jump on the meat'
> - 'Old Talon stares at his meat'

Comment: Not sure what the two "_Incorrect_"s are doing there... While noting your first example isn't a "vertical list", either of the two ways _could_ be acceptable, but which is "better" is more of a stylistic/layout question than one of the English language.

Comment: Good point re: the first example. I'm not sure why it didn't come out as a vertical list (frustrating!).

Edited

Comment: I prefer the first option. However, it means you end up ending a question without a question mark, which feels wrong.

Comment: The 'incorrect' is just our house style. I presume you're referring to the fact that it is a fragment.

Comment: Why would I need to end a question in a question mark. Can't you tell what a question is just by looking at the words.

Comment: You could put a question mark at the end of each of the list items in the first instance and then it wouldn't be missing. However, that makes no sense with your specific example. I think the second (bottom) list is correct because it reads like a multiple choice question then. The alternative would be something like: Could you infer that: (option/list) from these quotes?

Comment: When you say that using 'incorrect' is just your house style, that doesn't explain it. What is your house style rule for its use? ("Add the word 'incorrect' when . . .") I presume you are marking each as incorrect for a specific reason—and that you're asking how you could form a list so that 'incorrect' would *not* need to be used? If so, we need to know the rules behind your use of 'incorrect' before that can be answered.